# What is wrong with string escape character?

Tags: ios, swift, escaping

Following expression

```
let qs = "\' \(loggedInUserSettingRecordName!) \'";
```

plotted out like this:

```
(lldb) po qs
"\' 10208273026137463 \'"
```

Why? Swift docs says:

```
Special Characters in String Literals

    String literals can include the following special characters:

        The escaped special characters \0 (null character), \\ (backslash), \t (horizontal tab), \n (line feed), \r (carriage return), \" (double quote) and \' (single quote)
```

---

Tried without escaping:

```
let qs = "' \(loggedInUserSettingRecordName!) '";
```

results:

```
(lldb) po qs
"\' 10208273026137463 \'"
```

Comment: There's no need to escape the `'` character.

Comment: Tried without escaping, but same issue.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about the debugger's output. Do you see the backslashes where it matters?

Comment: Where are you looking at your result? single quotes should work whether or not they're escaped.